# HTML Code disappears from ShoutEm Builder

Tags: html, react-native, shoutem

I have a HTML5 element I'd like to include in the body of one of my ShoutEm screens in ShoutEm builder. When I paste the element's HTML code into the description box, it shows the element, but the code and element disappears the moment I click anywhere in the builder.

Is there any way to make the HTML code stick and not disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 editor included in the content settings pages for the CMS is limited in it's uses.

It doesn't support:

- Inline styling
- `<iframe>` embeds other than YouTube
- Nested components inside of text components (e.g. `<br/>` or `<span>` inside `<p>`

Comment: Thanks. Is this by design? It seems a bit bizarre that the iframe embedded element shows properly in the preview box, but it disappears when an attempt to save it is made.