# Shoutem: where is screen-specific data saved in a cloned project?

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I've created an app using Shoutem Builder, but the builder isn't able to do [everything I need it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757184/html-code-disappears-from-shoutem-builder). I've created a local copy with `shoutem clone` so I can edit the screens myself; however, I'm unable to locate exactly where I would find the file(s) to add the code to the dozen or so blank 'About' screens I have in my app.

I've thoroughly searched the documentation, and while it's got information on editing a screen created using the CLI, I'm unable to find any thing related to how to locate and edit individual screens created in the builder. Would these screens need to be deleted using the builder and created one-by-one using the CLI in order to be edited locally?

Answer (score 0):

`AppName/extensions/shoutem.about/app/screens/AboutScreen.js`, as seen [here](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/blob/master/shoutem.about/app/screens/AboutScreen.js).

Each screen you add re-uses the same code from the About extension. It'd be rather wasteful to create a dozen of the same files.

If you need each of the different screens to have a different layout, you can consider making custom layouts for the About extension and then use each of those for each of the separate screens on the Builder. You can find out how to make custom layouts [here](https://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-extensions#2-extend-the-extension).